# How to "thin" a large CSV file to extract its salient features?

Tags: algorithm, csv, sampling, downsampling

I need to [downsample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downsampling), or ***"thin"***, a large data set: 275 MB CSV file consisting of 10 Million data points. Each data point is a `time,voltage` pair formatted (for example) as follows:

> 3.387903904E-04,2.68E-02

***or, 338.79 usec, 0.0268 volts***

The data were generated during a measurement on an oscilloscope. Following is a screen shot of the full measurement:

[image: original screenshot of measurement]

The duration of the full measurement pictured above is 2 msec. Time is the horizontal axis, voltage is the vertical axis. The oscilloscope recorded a measurement every 0.2 nsec (2<sup>-10</sup> sec);  thus, 10<sup>7</sup> data points in the full measurement. The voltage ranged from a *nominal* 0 volts to a *nominal* +5 volts.

I need to reduce the size of this data set "substantially" (99.9% or more) without losing the prominent features. Rather than obfuscate this question with a lot of information that may be irrelevant to a proposed downsampling/thinning approach, I will let the comments determine what information is required.

However, I will add this: Referring to the Figure below, the data points leading up to the trigger may be represented by only two (2) data points: one at the origin, the other (approx) 200usec later at the "trigger point". The data set contains 10<sup>6</sup> data points during this interval. Similarly, there are other "long" periods of near zero changes in voltage that may be represented by only two (2) data points.

[image]

As my original question was **CLOSED** because it was judged to be requesting an opinion, I have completely overhauled and re-written this question in a bid to have it ***RE-OPENED***. And in a further effort to avoid the **opinion label**, my question is now as follows:

How would I go about using `awk` or `mlr` to downsample or "thin" the dataset described above? Some notes follow that may or may not be pertinent to a proposed answer.

---

#### NOTES:

1. I looked at two algorithms for downsampling: [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm), and [VW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visvalingam%E2%80%93Whyatt_algorithm).  It's not clear to me that these algorithms will "thin" the data set sufficiently, but I'll happily consider an answer based on either of these algorithms - or any others.
2. It will be apparent to most, but just in case: A **useful** answer must capture not only "low-to-high" (*0 volt-to-5 volt*) transitions, but "high-to-low" (*5 volt-to-0 volt*) transitions as well.
3. A simplistic threshold approach may not be a **useful** answer because:

> During the transition process from "low-to-high" or "high-to-low", there may be many *intermediate* steps of varying voltage values. Some sort of "look-ahead" function may be required to determine the next data point to be included in the "thinned" data set.

Comment: Looks like can choose the parameters for RDP or VW to get the desired amount of points

Comment: @LawrenceWu: Are you referring to the  *epsilon* parameter? It seems that would *influence* the number of data points, but not set it to an absolute value. Or am I missing something?

Comment: There are many ways to take random samples from a CSV file. You can use the Linux shell command `shuf`, or you can read your data into a Pandas dataframe and call `sample()`. Is there anything specific about your data that necessitates a specialized algorithm?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010: Nothing except that *random* sampling strikes me as inappropriate for this data set. I need to reduce 10 million samples of a non-linear waveform to about 5,000 - a 99.95% reduction. Maybe I could get something useful, but maybe not. A *threshold-based* scheme makes sense. And the RDP & VW algorithms make sense. "Random" would, by definition, discard some features that I need to retain.

Comment: Yes, for VW you can pick exactly the number of points, and with RDP you can tune epsilon (for example by binary search)

Comment: FWIW: I've made 3 attempts to have the erroneous "opinion-based" flag removed, so I'll give up. But for anyone who's interested, [I did get an answer here - on U&L SE.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/627800/can-awk-sum-a-column-over-a-specified-number-of-lines)

Comment: This is sad.  It seems like this question should be open.  I didn't look for the original question that may have solicited an opinion, but this one does not seem to do so.  SO needs to have an "appeal" button.

Comment: @Seamus: I tried to make an appeal to SO moderators by flagging the question.  They declined to help.  I think you cannot get this question reopened, even though you changed it to no longer be opinion-based.  If you're still interested in getting answers, I think the only way to do it would be to open a new question with the same content.  Good luck!

Comment: @Mr.LanceESloan: Thanks for your effort, but I decided months ago this was a waste of time. As I mentioned in my earlier comment, I got a good answer in the U&L forum. I also appreciated Lawrence Wu's comments, but not being a mathematician, I worried about VW maintaining the voltages as a **function** of time - as opposed to a line on a map - which obviously needn't be a function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to implement a random sample:

```
awk -v r=0.005 '/.*/ { if(rand() < r) { print } }' data.csv
```

This prints out the first value and only subsequent values if they are greater than the delta voltage thresholds:

```
 awk -v delta=0.5 -v FS=, 'NR == 1 { print; last=$2 } NR > 1 { if(last - $2 <= -delta || last - $2 >= delta) { print }; last=$2 }' data.csv
```

With the example data:

```
  1,1 # low
  2,1 # filter out
  3,2 # high
  4,2 # filter out
  5,1 # low
  6,1 # filter out
```

Here is the result that I am getting (low to high, and high to low transitions):

```
   awk -v delta=1 ... data.csv
   1,1 # low
   3,2 # high
   5,1 # low
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking for an opinion. If you don't have one, then just say you don't know.

Comment: There are explicit close statuses for requests for opinions.

Comment: Everything is an opinion. The answer you gave with the `awk` command is your opinion.

Comment: You are entitled to believe in whatever you want.  These are probably the most relevant link to support my case that's it's off-topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: "Off-topic" - or "requesting an opinion"?

Comment: I appreciate the effort that went into this answer, but it seems to have a significant flaw: It recognizes "low-to-high" transitions in the data, but cannot recognize a "high-to-low" transition.

Comment: I tweaked the code to use <= and >= instead of < and > to make the example values easier to read.   Then ran example data with a low-high-low transition and it seems to give me the expected result.